# Filtered HTML list: making li elements initially invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="orasul tau..">

<ul id="myUL">
    <li>Bucuresti</li>
    <li>Cluj</li>
    <li>Timisoara</li>
</ul>
```

And this is my scipt:

```
var value = $('#myInput').val();
if(value.length == 0) {
    $("#myUL li").style.display = "none";
}

$('#myInput').bind('keyup', function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();    
    $("ul li").each(function(index, value) {
        currentName = $(value).text()
        if( currentName.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
           $(value).show();
        } else {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });   
});
```

I want to filter the elements of the ul based on the text in the input.

Everything is working perfectly without that initial `if` statement, but I want all the `li` elements to initially have `diplay:none`. Adding that `if` deactivates the whole filtering. Any possible solution for how I could do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$("#myUL li").style.display = "none"` doesn't make sense. `$("#myUL li")` is jQuery instance object, not HTMLElement. So it doesn't have property `style`.

Use `$("#myUL li").hide()` to hide all elements.

However, the better approach is to use CSS to hide `LI` initially and trigger one search on page load if `myInput` has value:

```js
var $input = $('#myInput').on('input', function() {
  var searchString = $(this).val();
  $("ul li").each(function(index, value) {
    var currentName = $(value).text()
    var shouldShow = searchString.length && currentName.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) > -1;
    
    if (shouldShow) {
      $(value).show();
    } else {
      $(value).hide();
    }
  });
});

var value = $input.val();

if (value.length !== 0) {
 $input.trigger('keyup');
}
```

```css
#myUL li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="orasul tau..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>Bucuresti</li>
  <li>Cluj</li>
  <li>Timisoara</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, working good! However, all the elements are still swhown after writing some text in the input box and then deleting it? Any idea for how I could fix that?

Comment: @M.Vlad Check that `searchString` is not empty and use it as part of show/hide condition. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#myUL li').hide()` like the following:

```js
var value = $('#myInput').val();
if(value.length == 0) {
  $('#myUL li').hide();
}

$('#myInput').bind('keyup', function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();    
    $("ul li").each(function(index, value) {
        currentName = $(value).text()
      if(searchString == ''){$('#myUL li').hide(); }
      else if( currentName.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
       $(value).show();
      } else {
        $(value).hide();
      }
  });   
});

function myFunction(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="orasul tau..">

<ul id="myUL">
    <li>Bucuresti</li>
    <li>Cluj</li>
    <li>Timisoara</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Working good! However, all the elements are still shown after writing some text in the input box and then deleting it. Any idea for how I could fix that?

Comment: @M.Vlad, I have updated the snippet. Please check and let me know --Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmhw3u5n/1/

js

```
    var value = $('#myInput').val();
//if(value.length == 0) {
    //$("#myUL li").style.display = "none";
//}

$('#myInput').bind('keyup', function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();        
    if(searchString == '') {
        document.getElementById('myUL').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('myUL').style.display = 'block';
    }
    $("ul li").each(function(index, value) {
        currentName = $(value).text()
        if( currentName.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
           $(value).show();
        } else {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });   
});
```